# Odin project rock, paper, scissors game

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I can't figure out why the game is not keeping track of the player's score, it's supposed to alert a message after you win 5 rounds but it doesn't alert anything which makes me think that it's just not keeping track of the score when running the `game()` function.

```
<script>
    const rty = Math.floor(Math.random())
    let option1 = "rock"
    let option2 = "paper"
    let option3 = "scissors"
    let playerScore = 0
    let computerScore = 0

function getComputerChoice() {
    if (rty <= 0.33) {
    return option1
    }
    else if (rty <= 0.66) {
    return option2 
    }
    else if (rty <= 0.99) {
    return option3
    }
}
    function play(x, enter) {
    x = prompt("Enter your choice").toLowerCase()
    enter = getComputerChoice()
    if (x === "paper" && enter === "rock") {
        return alert("You Win! Paper beats Rock");
        playerScore++;
    }   
    else if (x === "rock" && enter === "paper") {
        return alert("You Lose! Paper beats Rock");
        computerScore++;
    }
    else if (x === "scissors" && enter === "rock") {
        return alert("You Lose! Rock beats Scissors");
        computerScore++;
    }
    else if (x === "rock" && enter === "scissors") {
        return alert("You Win! Rock beats Scissors");
        playerScore++;
        
    }
    else if (x === "scissors" && enter === "paper") {
            return alert("You Win! Scissors beats Paper");
            playerScore++;
            
        }
        else if (x === "paper" && enter === "scissors") {
            return alert("You Lose! Scissor beats Paper");
            computerScore++;
        }
        else if (x === enter) {
            return alert("It's a tie")
        }
        else {
            return alert("Enter a valid input plox") 
        }
    }
    
    function game() {
        let win = "Winner"
        let lose = "Loser"

        for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            play()
            if (playerScore === 5) {
              return alert(win)
              }
            }
         }
    </script>
```

I put the variable in the global scope so that shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: Your code only defines variables and functions, but no function gets called. There must be something missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're incrementing the scores after `return`ing, meaning those lines aren't executed. You should increment the scores before returning. E.g.:

```js
if (x === "paper" && enter === "rock") {
    // First increment the score
    playerScore++;

    // Then return
    return alert("You Win! Paper beats Rock");
}
```